# How to make python create variables, without the user creating the variables?

Tags: python, variables

I am making a program in Python where you would enter an integer and then it would create integer many variables (if that makes sense). How would I make Python do this?
EDIT: Sorry for a contradictory title! :)

Comment: How big is your integer going to be?

Comment: Votes to close question due to no effort whatsoever. Python build-ins set(), setattr() functions.

Comment: Probably there's some other problem in design - why would you want your user decide the number of variables? Why not using lists or sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contradicts itself, you want to prompt the user to enter an integer value that would in return, create that many values available for use. Just a note on:

> ...make python create variables, without the user creating the variables?

You're creating the values using python, so indirectly, python is creating them, the user is entering how many values he/she wants using a python program, so indirectly, the user is also creating them.

With that being said, a list will suffice for this:

```
num_of_vars=int(input("Enter number of int variables you want to create:"))
vals=[0] * num_of_vars
print(vals)
```

The `input()` function prompts the user it's argument, i.e , the string "Enter number of int variables you want to create." However, this needs to be treated as an integer value. So we explicitly convert it using `int()`.

The [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `vals` is initialized with `num_of_vars` elements (input of user) all with the value of 0. So if we input 5 and print this list out, we get:

`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Python created variables without the user creating them.

However, if you actually mean to write the "variables" in code, then that's entirely different, and can be done with nothing more than the `input()` function, [python input and output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#input-and-output) and a ton of boredom.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, sorry for a poor choice of wording in the question